# jQuery Datepicker Passing 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a DateOfBirth field in a view model like this,

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

and the view that has this,

```
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
</li>
```

and some jQuery to add the datepicker,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({
        yearRange: '1906:1994',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: 'bounce'
    });
</script>
```

If I choose a date such as 07/19/1981, July 19, 1981 it passes the value into the controller as 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM and I get the error "The value '07/19/1981' is not valid for Date Of Birth."  I've noticed that if the value for the day is 12 or less it passes it goes through but if the day is above 12 it will fail. So I tried changing the format in the datepicker to

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```

and then when I submit the form it gives the error "The field Date Of Birth must be a date."

What do I need to do to fix this? I'd like to be able to display the date as month/day/year if at all possible.

Comment: Is the error server side or client side?

Comment: Well the first error I believe is server side, it submits then returns the error that the value '07/19/1981' is not valid for Date Of Birth but the second one where it says "The field Date Of Birth must be a date" appears to be client side since it appear immediately and doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531247/jquery-datepickers-dateformat-how-to-integrate-with-net-current-culture-date

Comment: What do your logs tell you when you submit? You should be able to tell by looking at your server side logs whether or not the problem exists there or not. Also, you can look at the response from the server in your Chrome debugger NET tab or Firebug NET tab.

Comment: I've tried adding the helper in the link you posted and it formats the date in the textbox to the 19/07/1981. Same error when I submit, "The field Date Of Birth must be a date" and doesn't submit, just loads up the datepicker again and prompts for another date.

Comment: what culture are you using in your app? make sure you use same format like in your culture.

Comment: Hmmm, this could be it. I just added en-US in my web.config and it works now. I'm in Canada though but I guess I should be fine either way. Thanks.

Comment: @user1066133 that didn't solve it for me...and I have the exact same errors

Answer (score 0):

Try using datetime picker like this :

```
$("#StartDate").datetimepicker({ timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss', dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
```

You can include timepicker from this [link](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). I think the format you provided is wrong check MSDN for correct datetime format string, but in my case worked.
You can also add correct format to your datepicker.

Comment: Are you saying the op has to have a timepicker too in order for this to work?

Comment: I'm wondering this too. I'd rather not have to have it if at all possible. I just need a simple date.

Comment: @user1066133 - Did you try setting your date format from `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` to `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` like in Floradu's example? It's quite possible you may not need a timepicker and that you're just representing your Dateformat wrong. Also, Floradu should include his NET server side bindings in his answer for it to be complete. If you're using a different object on the server-side, that could affect the outcome as well.

Comment: Just tried changing it to the format you suggested and I get the same client side validation error "The field Date Of Birth must be a date" and it loads up the datepicker again to prompt for a valid date...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mentioning yearRange, Try minDate,maxDate like

```
minDate: new Date(1906,0,1),
maxDate: new Date(1994,11,31)
```

Comment: Strangely enough, now when I select the Year dropdown from the datepicker it only gives me 1984-1994 when I use minDate/maxDate with those values.

Comment: I think only first 10 years are shown.. Select 1984 in the dropdown, it'll show the next 10 years list and so on...