# Issue in datetime format when applying it from CultureInfo datetime format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having a datepicker in which I am binding its format to the datetime format of the Culture. But the problem here is, if the year part is coming as YYYY then the year part is repeating two times.

Here are the detailed explanation:

> **aspx File:**

```
<div>
         <p>Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>  
</div>
```

> **Jquery:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var cultureInfoFormat = '<%=  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString()%>
     $('#datepicker').datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: cultureInfoFormat
     
                    }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
     
  </script>
```

> If the format is coming as "dd-MM-yyyy" or having the year part as YYYY then the UI is displaying the date
> as **29-January-20192019**
>
> I have tried replacing the YYYY part by YY then the result is coming
> as expected i.e **29-January-2019**
>
> But I don't want to apply that replace string because I may not know
> how many configurations I will have to make.

Please help me with this.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123547/1225270 Instead of setting actual format of .net Culture, convert it to a format that datepicker would understand.

Comment: @arunes Hey. I checked the link. I have already tried this solution that replaces yyyy with yy. But I am looking for some other solution because this solution may fail for few cases.